# Should I return from a function early or use an if statement?

Tags: coding-style, conditions, control-structures

I've often written this sort of function in both formats, and I was wondering if one format is preferred over another, and why.

```java
public void SomeFunction(bool someCondition)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

or

```java
public void SomeFunction(bool someCondition)
{
    if (!someCondition)
        return;

    // Do Something
}
```

I usually code with the first one since that is the way my brain works while coding, although I think I prefer the 2nd one since it takes care of any error handling right away and I find it easier to read

Comment: I'm a bit late for this discussion so I won't put this in an answer; I also thought about this two years ago: http://lecterror.com/articles/view/code-formatting-and-readability I find the second easier to read, modify, maintain and debug. But maybe that's just me :)

Comment: Related: [Where did the notion of"one return only" come from?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from)

Comment: There is an unstated assumption in the question's examples and in the answers that we are not considering early return from within loops. They can make reasoning about a function a good deal more complicated, and are harder to brush off as being a harmless convenience.

Comment: now this question is a fine example of an opinion-based question

Comment: so what if there is no absolute proof in one or another direction? When enough argumentation is provided in one and another direction and there is a voting if the answer is correct - it makes it very useful. I find closing questions like this to be harmful to the value of this site.

Comment: And I like opinion based questions and answers. They tell me what majority prefers and that lets me to write the code for others to read.

Comment: 1- Mostly it's **opinion-based** & personal flavor preference 

2- It depends on **what the function returns**, for example: 

A- if function always return a number (or always return an string, or always return a boolean, or doesn't return anything) then multi-exits might be better, 

B- but if function returns an object (or an array, or different return type for each condition) then nested IFs might be better/easier

Comment: I really don't know why this is closed. Don't come back with a list of guidelines, caz if this closed because it violate guidelines, then the guidelines needs to change.

Answer (score 398, accepted):

I prefer the second style.  Get invalid cases out of the way first, either simply exiting or raising exceptions as appropriate, put a blank line in there, then add the "real" body of the method.  I find it easier to read.

Comment: Smalltalk calls these "guard clauses". At least that's what Kent Beck calls them in Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns; I don't know if it's common parlance.

Comment: Not in Delphi though right?  I was under the impression that "Exit" was considered harmful.

Comment: @Peter: Hmm?  I don't think I've heard that before in the Delphi community.  Do you have any links?

Comment: @Mason, you'd know better than me.  My Delphi community consists of people who call it "Delphee".  It just seems like Result := something; Exit; isn't so good looking, therefore it's bad.  Just a prejudice though.

Comment: @Peter: Well, if it makes it look any better, since D2009 we've had the ability to write `Exit(value);` instead of making it two statements. :)

Comment: RE: Delphi Exit's http://stackoverflow.com/q/1021498/1765 answers are about 3/4 in favor of exit/pragmatism.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened with my earlier comment - feel like I walked into the wrong bar or something. Surprised nobody flagged my comment for abuse :}

Comment: Exiting early allows you to pop stuff off your limited mental stack. :)

Comment: I've previously heard this referred to as "the Bouncer Pattern" - get rid of bad cases before they get in the door.

Comment: I'd even go as far and say this definitely is the ONLY right thing to do.

Comment: Plus you don't keep adding indents if you get rid of the border cases at the beginning.

Comment: And some coding standards still require a Single Exit... :(

Comment: Throw exception? Yes. Early exit? Not so much.

Comment: The problem with this is that when you overlook a possible bad condition for your following code, your codes gets executed nonetheless. If, on the other hand, you only execute your code when the correct conditions are met (first example in OP), then you do not have to fear the unknown. Therefore I choose the first example as the best, imo.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: I am wrong of course, because the if-condition will evaluate to true too when I forget to add the necessary condition checks, so my preferred way isn't any different from my not preferred way.

Comment: I like this way, as well. It allows filtering down the amount of code to run to only the cases where all conditions are met.  I usually use this in public methods to filter out invalid cases, then call an internal method to actually run the code for relevant matches.

Comment: what if I have nested if statements and also nested if in else conditions. Then how I will exit from the all if statements.

Comment: @klaar, "The problem with this is that when you overlook a possible bad condition for your following code, your codes gets executed nonetheless." - you are totally wrong here. Examples from OP have totally equivalent logic since it uses absolutely same `someCondition`. Please read again before you state such a nonsense.

Comment: Talking about reading again, please read my comment following the wrong comment. I already know, thanks.

Comment: Just a personal preference but if an entire function will be skipped based on a condition, I'd prefer to guard in the calling function. If multiple/complex condition checks are made, I'd extract the entire condition check into a separate function entirely.

Answer (score 168):

Definitely the latter.  The former doesn't look bad right now, but when you get more complex code, I can't imagine anyone would think this:

```java
public int SomeFunction(bool cond1, string name, int value, AuthInfo perms)
{
    int retval = SUCCESS;
    if (someCondition)
    {
        if (name != null && name != "")
        {
            if (value != 0)
            {
                if (perms.allow(name)
                {
                    // Do Something
                }
                else
                {
                    reval = PERM_DENY;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                retval = BAD_VALUE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            retval = BAD_NAME;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        retval = BAD_COND;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

is more readable than

```java
public int SomeFunction(bool cond1, string name, int value, AuthInfo perms)
{
    if (!someCondition)
        return BAD_COND;

    if (name == null || name == "")
        return BAD_NAME;

    if (value == 0)
        return BAD_VALUE;

    if (!perms.allow(name))
        return PERM_DENY;

    // Do something
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I fully admit I never understood the advantage of single exit points.

Comment: +1. I only do the early return thing when there is some condition to check right up at the start. But if the returns would be happenining throughout a big chunk of code like that, I go with the second option. :)

Comment: The advantage of single a exit point is that... there's a single exit point!  With your example, there's several points which could return.  With a more complex function, that could turn into a hunt-the-exit-point when the format of the return value changes. Of course, there's times when forcing a single exit point doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JohnL big functions are the problem, not multiple exit points. Unless you're working in a context where an additional function call will slow down your code immensely, of course...

Comment: @Yar: True, but the point stands.  I'm not going to try and convert anyone, and I was just pointing out the advantage of going for as few exit points as possible (and Jason's example was kind of straw man anyway).  Just next time you're pulling your hair out trying to figure out why SomeFunction sometimes returns odd values, maybe you'll wish you could add a logging call *just before* the return.  Much easier to debug if there's only one of the buggers! :)

Comment: JohnL, that's another point, too. Early returns should only return null or void. If you have multiple things that you need to return, early returns are very confusing.

Comment: I agree with JohnL's situation of "why did funcA return X", and finding half a dozen returns scattered through the program.  That's a situation where the function should be refactored to better demonstrate what happens, & why - which results in a single return from funcA!

Comment: I guess my rule of thumb is "return early for error conditions that prevent the func, then func does its thing and returns.  If you need two logical blocks each with their own return, they should become their own functions, and start from beginning."

Comment: @Jason Viers As if a single `return value;` helps!?! Then one has to hunt half a dozen `value = ...`, with the disadvantage that you are never sure that value will not be changed between this assignment and the final return. At least an immediate return is clear that nothing will change the result anymore.

Comment: @Sjoed: I second Sjoerd here. If you want to log the result, you can log at the caller site. If you want to know the reason, you have to log at each exit point/assignment so both are identical in this aspect.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's not so easy to log the returned value in the caller if the function is being called from within an expression, rather than an assignment statement.

Comment: @mk7: Log an inline wrapper function, which forwards arguments and result, and log what you wish; it will be more reliable than expecting that no-one adds a new return without logging. Note that I expect the need for fine-grained logging to be rare; otherwise you need TBs of logging space quickly.

Comment: Instead of inverting the conditions in the nested-if-statement kind of method, you can keep the conditions and handle the negative cases BEFORE the positive cases, which means the positive case will ALSO come at the end. Granted, it will be succeeded by a whole number of closing curcly braces, but it's still at the end.

Comment: Single exit point generally means more indentation and the less indentation the easier things are to read. Why is figuring out what a function returned difficult? Who isn't stepping through their function that they know is an issue to see what it's doing with the given input? It's not difficult.

Comment: @JohnL  I've found I can mitigate your complaint by keeping the entire `if` statement on one line which puts all the `return`s out to the right.

Comment: Code refactoring is much easier in first type of implementation

Comment: how this answer got so many points !? duh ...

Answer (score 32):

**It depends** - In general I am not going to go out of my way to try and move a bunch of code around to break out of the function early - the compiler will generally take care of that for me. That said though, if there are some basic parameters at the top that I need and can't continue otherwise, I will breakout early. Likewise, if a condition generates a giant `if` block in function I will have it breakout early as a result of that as well.

That said though, if a function requires some data when it is called, I'm usually going to be throwing an exception (see example) as opposed to just returning.

```java
public int myFunction(string parameterOne, string parameterTwo) {
  // Can't work without a value
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameterOne)) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("parameterOne");
  } 
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameterTwo)) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("parameterTwo");
  }

  // ...      
  // Do some work
  // ...

  return value;
}
```

Comment: And if the end result is maintainable, who cares which style was selected?

Comment: @Jeff Siver - Thus why this tends to be a "holy-war" style question, at the end of the day it comes down to personal preference and whatever an internal style guide says.

Comment: The key take-away here is that he's throwing an exception instead of returning early. The return value should not be re-purposed for validity checks. What if you had various conditions and wanted to let the code using the method know why it failed? Suddenly you might return actual business data, nothing (empty result) or many different strings, codes, numers, ... from one single method. Just to describe why it failed. No thanks.

Comment: what about cyclomatic complexity as my compiler suggests? isnt it better to not nest code if one can help it?

Answer (score 24):

**I prefer the early return.**

If you have one entry point and one exit point then you always have to track the entire code in your head all the way down to the exit point (you never know if some other piece of code bellow does something else to the result, so you have to track it up until the exist). You do that no mater which branch determines the final result. This is hard to follow.

With one entry and multiple exists, you return when you have your result and don't bother tracking it all the way down to see that nobody does anything else to it (because there won't be anything else since you returned). It's like having the method body split into more steps, which each step with the possibility to return the result or let the next step try its luck.

Answer (score 13):

In C programming where you have to manually clean-up there is a lot to be said for one-point return. Even if there is no need right now to clean something up, someone might edit your function, allocate something and need to clean it up before return. If that happens it will be a nightmare job looking through all the return statements.

In C++ programming you have destructors and even now scope-exit guards. All these need to be here to ensure the code is exception-safe in the first place, so code is well guarded against early exit and therefore doing so has no logical downside and is purely a style issue.

I am not knowledgeable enough about Java, whether "finally" block code will get called and whether finalizers can handle the situation of needing to ensure something happens.

C# I certainly can't answer on.

D-language gives you proper built-in scope-exit guards and therefore is well-prepared for early exit and therefore should not present an issue other than style.

Functions should of course not be so long in the first place, and if you have a huge switch statement your code is probably also badly factored.

Comment: C++ allows something called return value optmization which permits the compiler to essentially omit the copy operation that would normally occur when you return a value.  However, under various conditions that's hard to do, and multiple return values is one of those cases.  In other words, using multiple return values in C++ can actually make your code slower.  This certainly hold on MSC, and given that is would be quite tricky (if not impossible) to implement RVO with multiple possible return values, it's likely a problem in all compilers.

Comment: In C, just use `goto` and, possibly, a two-point return. Example (code formatting not possible in comments): `foo() { init(); if (bad) goto err; bar(); if (bad) goto err; baz(); return 0; err: cleanup(); return 1; }`

Comment: Instead of a goto I prefer "Extract Method".  When you think you need to implement a return value variable or a goto, in an effort to ensure your cleanup code is always called, that's a Smell that you need to break it up into multiple functions.  This allows you to simplify your complex conditional code using Guard Clauses and other early-return techniques, while still ensuring your cleanup code always runs.

Comment: "someone might edit your function" - this is such a ridiculous explanation for decision making. Anyone can do anything in the future. It doesn't mean that you should do something specific today to prevent someone from breaking things in the future.

Comment: Called making your code maintainable. In the real world code is written for business purposes and sometimes a developer later on needs to change it. At the time I wrote that answer though I had patched CURL to introduce caching and recall the spaghetti mess that it was that really needed a proper rewrite in modern C++

Answer (score 9):

Early returns for-the-win.  They can seem ugly, but much less ugly than big `if` wrappers, especially if there's multiple conditions to check.

Answer (score 9):

**I use both.**

If `DoSomething` is 3-5 lines of code then the code just look beautiful using the first formatting method.

But if it has many more lines than that, then I prefer the second format.  I don't like when the opening and closing brackets are not on the same screen.

Comment: Beautiful no way! Too much indentation!

Comment: @JimmyKane There's only so much indentation which can happen in 3-5 lines, especially as you need 2 (?) lines per level the rest gets indented: One for the control-structure and start of block, one for end of block.

Answer (score 8):

A classic reason for single-entry-single-exit is that otherwise the formal semantics become unspeakably ugly otherwise (same reason GOTO was considered harmful).

Put another way, it's easier to reason about when your software will exit the routine if you have only 1 return. Which is also an argument against exceptions.

Typically I minimize the early-return approach.

Comment: but for a formal analysis tool you can synthesize an outer function with the semantics the tool needs, and keep the code human readable.

Comment: @Tim. That depends on how much dinking you want to do and what you're analyzing. I find SESE fairly readable if the coder was sane about things.

Comment: My attitude to analysis is shaped by optimizations from the Self project. 99% of dynamic method calls can be statically resolved and eliminated. so then you can analyze some pretty straight line code. As a working programmer, I can reliably assume most code I'll work on was written by average programmers. So they won't write very nice code.

Comment: @Tim: Fair enough. Although I do feel compelled to point out that static languages still have a lot of play.

Comment: A reason that doesn't hold in the face of exceptions. Which is why single-exit is great in C, but doesn't buy you anything in C++.

Comment: @peterchen: Like I said, SESE is an argument against exceptions. "action at a distance"

Comment: @Paul Nathan: Like I said, exceptions are an argument against SESE ;)  Still, in an exception-free C++ (i.e. where I can use RAII / ScopeGuards) I'd go with early returns rather than nesting, because arguing gets easier when you know "the code will reach this point only when the following conditions are (not) met". It depends on where you put the returns, though.

Comment: "_it's easier to reason about when your software will exit the routine if you have only 1 return_" -- Disagree. I've maintened a giant VB codebase where SESE was applied. Every function has a `ret` variable that holds what should be returned, and that variable is reassigned many times. which makes a hell to keep track of its value. Early exiting makes code easier to reason about.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I prefer to do pass/fail condition checks at the beginning.  That allows me to group most of the most common failures at the top of the function with the rest of the logic to follow.

Answer (score 6):

It depends.

Early return if there is some obvious dead end condition to check for right away that would make running the rest of the function pointless.*

Set Retval + single return if the function is more complex and could have multiple exit points otherwise (readability issue).

**This can often indicate a design problem. If you find that a lot of your methods need to check some external/paramater state or such before running the rest of the code, that's probably something that should be handled by the caller.*

Comment: When I write code that may be shared, my mantra is "Assume Nothing. Trust No One."  You should always validate your inputs and any external state you depend on.  Better to throw an exception than possibly corrupt something because somebody gave you bad data.

Comment: @TMN: Good point.

Comment: Key point here is that in OO you *throw an exception*, not *return*. Multiple returns can be bad, multiple exception throws aren't necessarily a code smell.

Comment: @MichaelK: A method should an exception if the post-condition can't be met.  In some cases, a method should exit early because the post-condition has been achieved even before the function started.  For example, if one invokes a "Set control label" method to change a control's label to `Fred`, the window's label is already `Fred`, and setting the control's name to its present state would force a redraw (which, while potentially useful in some cases, would be annoying in the one at hand), it would be perfectly reasonable to have the set-name method early-exit if the old and new names match.

Answer (score 3):

**Use an If**

In Don Knuth's book about GOTO's I read him give a reason for always having the most likely condition come first in an if statement. Under the assumption that this is still a reasonable idea (and not one out of pure consideration for the speed of the era). I'd say early returns aren't good programming practice, especially considering the fact that they're more often than not used for error handling, unless your code is more likely to fail than not fail :-)

If you follow the above advice, you'd need to put that return at the bottom of the function, and then you might as well not even call it a return there, just set the error code and return it two lines hence. Thereby achieving the 1 entry 1 exit ideal.

**Delphi Specific...**

I'm of the mind that this is a good programming practice for Delphi programmers, although I don't have any proof.  Pre-D2009, we don't have an atomic way to return a value, we have `exit;` and `result := foo;` or we could just throw exceptions.

If you had to substitute

```js
if (true) {
 return foo;
}
```

for

```delphi
if true then 
begin
  result := foo; 
  exit; 
end;
```

you might just get sick of seeing that at the top of every one of your functions and prefer

```delphi
if false then 
begin
  result := bar;

   ... 
end
else
   result := foo;
```

and just avoid `exit` altogether.

Comment: With newer Delphis, it could be abbreviated to `if true then Exit(foo);` I use often the technique to first initialize `result` to `nil` or `FALSE` respectively, then checking all the error conditions and just `Exit;` if one is met. The success-case `result` is then (typically) set somewehere at the end of the method.

Comment: yeah, I like that new feature although is seems like it's just candy to appease Java programmers, next thing you know they'll be letting us define our variables inside the procedures.

Comment: And C# programmers. Yes, to be honest, I would find that indeed useful as it reduces the number of lines between declaration and use (IIRC there is even some metric for that, forgot the name).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the following statement:

> I'm personally a fan of guard clauses
>   (the second example) as it reduces the
>   indenting of the function. Some people
>   don't like them because it results in
>   multiple return points from the
>   function, but I think it's clearer
>   with them.

Taken from [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640700/what-coding-style-for-error-checking-is-better-and-why).

Comment: +1 For guard clauses. I also prefer a positively oriented guard eg: if (condition = false) return as opposed to if (!condition) return

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to write:

```c
if(someCondition)
{
    SomeFunction();
}
```

Comment: eww.  Is that pre-validation?  Or is it in a validation-dedicated mehtod `DoSomeFunctionIfSomeCondition`?

Comment: How does this keep your concerns separated?

Comment: You're violating encapsulation by making the function's implementation (its dependency logic) external.

Comment: This is great and perfectly correct (for a change, @Josh K :)). One huge advantage of this is that you are NAMING `SomeFunction` which makes your code more readable. @TMN, unless you're writing a single-function application, that's always true, isn't it?

Comment: If this is run in a public method and SomeFunction() is a private method in the same class it could be ok. But if anyone else is calling SomeFunction() you would have to duplicate the checks there. I find it better to make each method take care of what it needs to do its work, no one else should have to know that.

Comment: SomeFunction::WithCheck(condition)

Comment: This is definitely the style that Robert C. Martin proposes in "Clean Code".  A function should only do one thing.  However in "Implementation Patterns", Kent Beck suggests, of the two options proposed in the OP, the second is better.

Comment: @TMN You are stretching the concept of encapsulation beyond its breaking point. It is reasonable and sensible for code to call a function when, if and only if the algorithm it implements requires it (if the algorithm requires it but the function's preconditions have not been met, something is broken.) Your argument, taken to its logical conclusion, would forbid the calling of any function from within any conditionally-executed block, which in turn would mean that only the lowest-level functions could contain conditional statements or expressions, including loops.

Comment: This is only clean because it's 1 level of nesting. In the real world when people use this style you start seeing 4-5 levels of nesting. Forget that. The less nesting the more readable something is.

Answer (score 1):

Like you, I usually write the first one, but prefer the last one.
If i have a lot of nested checks i usually refactor to the second method.

I don't like how the error handling is moved away from the check.

```java
if not error A
  if not error B
    if not error C
      // do something
    else handle error C
  else handle error B
else handle error A
```

I prefer this:

```java
if error A
  handle error A; return
if error B
  handle error B; return
if error C
  handle error C; return

// do something
```

Answer (score 1):

I use early returns almost exclusively these days, to an extreme. I write this

```c
self = [super init];

if (self != nil)
{
    // your code here
}

return self;
```

as

```c
self = [super init];
if (!self)
    return;

// your code here

return self;
```

but it really doesn't matter. If you have more than one or two levels of nesting in your functions, they need to be busted up.

Comment: I agree. Indentation is what causes trouble in reading. The less indentation the better. Your simple example has the same level of indentation but that first example will surely grow to more indentations which require more brain power.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions on the top are called "preconditions". By putting `if(!precond) return;`, you are visually listing all preconditions.

Using the large "if-else" block may increase indent overhead (I forgot the quote about 3-level indents).

Comment: What? You can't do an early return in Java?  C#, VB (.NET and 6), and apparently Java (which I assumed did, but had to look up since I haven't used the language in 15 years) all allow early returns.  so don't accuse 'strongly-typed languages' as not having the feature. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884429/better-java-method-syntax-return-early-or-late

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to keep if statements small.

So, choosing between:

```python
if condition:
   line1
   line2
    ...
   line-n
```

and

```python
if not condition: return

line1
line2
 ...
line-n
```

I'd choose what you described as "early return".

Mind you, I don't care about early returns or whatever, I just really like to simplify the code, shorten the bodies of if statements, etc.

Nested if's and for's and while's are *horrible*, avoid them at all costs.

Answer (score -2):

As others say, it depends. For little functions that return values, I may code early returns.
But for sizeable functions, I like to always have a place in the code where I know I can put something that will get executed before it returns.

Answer (score -2):

I practice fail-fast at the function level. It keeps code consistent and clean (to me and those I've worked with). Because of that I always return early.

For some oft-checked conditions, you can implement aspects for those checks if you use AOP.